# Unity Coroutines

Tags: c#, unity3d, coroutine

Есть корутина:

```
private IEnumerator StartSearchNewTarget()
{
    List<Damagable> targetsDamagable;

    do
    {
        FindDamagableInArea(out targetsDamagable);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(SEARCH_DELAY);
    } 
    while (targetsDamagable.Count == 0);

    _target = ChooseTargetInArea(targetsDamagable);
}
```

Запускается она при помощи `StartCoroutine(StartSearchNewTarget());`.
Будет ли данная корутина выполнятся до вызова `StopCoroutine(StartSearchNewTarget());` или до окончания `_target = ChooseTargetInArea(targetsDamagable);`?

Спрашиваю, поскольку не нашел ответа на данный вопрос самостоятельно. Заранее прошу прощения, если ответ на похожий вопрос уже был дан.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IEnumerator` - это интерфейс. Реализовать его может или структура, или класс.

Метод, реализующий перечислитель компилируется в специальный метод, возвращающий такой экземпляр класса.

Его можно сохранить в переменную.

```
IEnumerator job = StartSearchNewTarget();
```

Эту корутину теперь можно запустить.

```
StartCoroutine(job);
```

Можно остановить.

```
StopCoroutine(job);
```

То есть принудительно остановить корутину можно только передав методу `StopCoroutine` тот же самый перечислитель, что и методу `StartCoroutine`.

Вызов `StopCoroutine(StartSearchNewTarget());` является нерабочим, так как он пытается остановить только что созданный перечислитель из вызова `StartSearchNewTarget()`, он даже не запущен.

Что касается остановки самого метода `StartSearchNewTarget`, то воспринимайте его как обычный метод, он либо выполнится до конца, либо будет принудительно вами остановлен, как я показал выше, и сама остановка произойдет на строчке с оператором `yield`.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Благодаря вам я разобрался с этим микро-кризисом)

Answer (score 0):

`StartSearchNewTarget()` в `StartCoroutine()` и `StopCoroutine()` это не одно и тоже. Можно запустить хоть 100 корутин одного и того же метода и все они будут работать, нужна ссылка на конкретную. [Читай документацию](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine.html).

> Будет ли данная корутина выполнятся до вызова StopCoroutine(StartSearchNewTarget());

Пока нет команды Stop, она будет работать.

> или до окончания _target = ChooseTargetInArea(targetsDamagable);?

Если корутина дошла до конца больше ей делать нечего, но можно и прервать на `yield` командой stop. Да, тут не "или", а "и".